# Insert with nested select

Tags: sql, oracle, select, insert, max

I am trying to insert data into kundvagn (cart), and select the highest ID from kundorder(orders).

Am I doing this completely wrong?

```
INSERT INTO kundvagn
(ordnr, artnr, antal),
VALUES(SELECT MAX(ordnr) from kundorder, 1, 3);
```

Answer (score 2):

You don't need the `values` keyword.  Instead, use `insert . . . select`:

```
INSERT INTO kundvagn (ordnr, artnr, antal)
    SELECT MAX(ordnr), 1, 3
    FROM kundorder;
```

Let me add that the code looks suspicious.  Inserting based on `MAX(ordnr)` does not take into account that other users/threads might be modifying the data.

Comment: and how do we make it take other threads into account ? Is read-locking `kundorder` before the query considered a right thing in this case?